# Cannot access Fiware Cosmos from Orion: Router has no route

Tags: ssh, fiware-orion, fiware, filab

I have Orion on a Fi-Lab VM, and have up until now accessed Cosmos via sftp and ssh, but now there seems to have been some sort of change made, because all I get now is this:

> ssh: connect to host X.X.80.46 port 22: No route to host

I also ran traceroute:

> traceroute to X.X.80.46, 30 hops max, 60 byte packets 
>   1  10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1)  0.927 ms  0.910 ms  0.952 ms 
>   2  X.X.82.1 (X.X.82.1)  13.478 ms  13.454 ms * 
>   3  * * X.X.192.157 (X.X.192.157)  14.021 ms 
>   4  fiwat-router.red.rediris.es (X.X.192.142)  13.873 ms  13.841 ms  13.835 ms 
>   5  fiwat-router.red.rediris.es (X.X.192.142)  3013.768 ms !H * *

and I ran ping:

> PING X.X.80.46 (X.X.80.46) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   From X.X.192.142 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

So fiwat-router seems to be the problem, is there any new configuration I need to do, or how can this be solved?

for reference (http://catalogue.fi-ware.org/enablers/publishsubscribe-context-broker-orion-context-broker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our cloud and infrastructure team is currently investigating this issue. It is not required any action from your side.